# Application properties not reading environment Variables

Tags: spring-boot, environment-variables, application.properties

I have a spring boot application. Currently, for a certain requirement, I am trying to read environment variables in application properties. This is what I have in my application.properties file:

notes.userName=${credentials.username}

In environment variables, the value for "credentials.username" is testUser. But while I run the program and try to read from notes.userName, the value is literally "${credentials.username}".

Is there anyother to set environment variables into application properties file.

NOTE: I am aware that I can read the environment variables directly but the requirement is to read  the environment variabes from application properties.

Comment: There can be many reasons why it is not reading. Which OS is it? Did you load the env files after you added the properties? Did you restart the system? Did you restart your application?

Comment: I am using windows. I am testing it using STS/eclipse. I have set the environment variables in the run/debug configuration and have restarted the application as well as the system.

Comment: How are you reading `notes.userName`? What made you conclude that it's not reading the environment variables?

Comment: because all the other properties that I am reading via application properties is showing fine.

Comment: Can you update on how you are reading the properties and what you are getting for `notes.userName`?

Comment: I am using @ value annotation

Comment: You need to read up https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before anyone can answer your question.